# PDO prepared statement trouble

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am currently trying to run a query where the current value of a mysql table column increase itself by 1... Let me show this with mysql query example

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

I am unable to do this in PDO prepared statement...

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET quantity=:quants+1 WHERE id=:userid";
$sql_prep = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql_prep->bindParam(":quants", what will i write here??);
$sql_prep->bindParam(":userid", $id);
$sql_prep->execute();
```

Help needed..! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass that as a parameter, just do:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE id=:userid";
$sql_prep = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql_prep->bindParam(":userid", $id);
$sql_prep->execute();
```

Comment: what about sql_injection? Will this query prevent sql injection...??

Comment: No injection, the only parameter you are passing to the query is userid. The quantity is internal to the database.

Comment: When transposing or manipulating data inside the database, you normally don't have to worry about SQL injection, the MySQL database is already dealing with native data and doesn't need to be coached on how to handle it. The exception to this rule is when you're *composing SQL queries* inside a stored procedure.

Comment: ok.. and what about the userid bindparam?.. do I have to do something like PDO::PARAM_INT for more safety or is it ok?

Comment: It's fine as is, the parameter datatype is optional. If your id field is an integer then you can add PDO::PARAM_INT just for completeness but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the to protect `quantity` as you're just augmenting a value already in the db.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE id=:userid";
```

You can also drop the bind line for the `:quants`

```
 $sql_prep = $db->prepare($sql);

 // NOT NEEEDED --> $sql_prep->bindParam(":quants", what will i write here??);

 $sql_prep->bindParam(":userid", $id);
 $sql_prep->execute();
```

Prepared statements are for protecting data being inserted from the outside into your db via your query.